# How to open text files with DropBox on Android?

Tags: dropbox, text-editor

I have the DropBox app on my Samsung Galaxy S 2.

It seemed to me that before, when I clicked on a text file, it would open a text editor. I think Dropbox had its own internal editor.

Now, however, when I open any plain text file, I get a message that says:

> Can't open textFileName
>
> Please download an app that can open this file.

I tried downloading numerous text editors from the market, but none of them linked with Dropbox.

How do I get text editing ability in Dropbox on Android?

Comment: I have Dropbox 2.0.1 and when I click on a text file (extension .txt), it offers to open it with "DB Text Editor", or with "HTMLViewer". It won't work for files without extensions, or with extensions that are not recognized. It doesn't use the file mime-type to determine whether it can be displayed with the text editor regardless of the extension.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Dropbox 2.0.1 (and in pre-2.0 versions, IIRC), you can tap on a text file and it can offer to open it in "DB Text Editor" which comes with the app (or some other editor which has been assigned to open files with .txt extension). Note that this won't work on just about any other file -- Dropbox does not recognize mime types, but rather uses the extension to pick a program to open a file with, even if the file in question contains text.

This also works with other file types -- for example, I am able to open my password database from KeepassDroid (extension .kbdx).