# How to register new extensions as text files (.Rmd)

Tags: files, dropbox, text-editor

I have R markdown (.Rmd extension file, uses Markdown syntax) file on my Dropbox. Regardless of trying to open it directly from Dropbox application or exporting it to my Android device, I see information that I have no application to open this file.

There was question about many extensions:
[How do I open a text file of any extension in Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/53707/how-do-i-open-a-text-file-of-any-extension-in-android)

but suggested answer does not work for me - I have DroidEdit, but my Android phone still claims that it is unable to open .Rmd file.
Obviously I can change an extension from .Rmd to .txt, but this is rather not efficient way of seeing files.

Is there any possibility to say Android 6, please **treat** **.Rmd as text** **files** / register new files extensions?

Please note that Dropbox app does not show me open file possibility as suggested in following thread:
[How to open text files with DropBox on Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/18816/how-to-open-text-files-with-dropbox-on-android)

**EDIT**:
Sample R Markdown file content:

````
---
title: "Mateusz"
author: "Sample R markdown file"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

## Including Plots

You can also embed plots, for example:

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
# Here is R! code:
plot(pressure)
```

Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.
````

Comment: Try opening with [Markdown X](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ryeeeeee.markdownx)

Comment: An alternative is using ES Explorer: you can open any extension as text.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems that Markdown X is not handling .Rmd extension. On the other hand ES Explorer workaround works.